# Camel Interceptor before each bean in pipeline

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have a lot of processors chained one by one in a way

```
   from(....)
    .bean(Processor1.class)
    .bean(Processor2.class)
    .bean(Processor3.class)
   to(...)
```

I want somehow intercept the flow before every 'bean'.
In the same time I don't want to edit routeConfig in a way

```
   from(....)
    .process()
    .bean(Processor1.class)
    .process()
    .bean(Processor2.class)
    .process()
    .bean(Processor3.class)
   to(...)
```

it is ugly and not scalable.
I checked already intercept and interceptFrom, but they are not helpful.  They intercepts only routes changes, but not the processors in scope of one route. Does anybody have any idea how to do that?

Comment: But the [intercept documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/intercept.html#Intercept-Intercept.1) says _the Exchange is intercepted before each processing step_.

Comment: the issue is that interceptors are affected by retry mechanism
So basically interceptor + step logic is retried. I need only step logic to be retried, and keep interception part completed by that time.

Comment: `intercept` is the Camel mechanism to do something between every route step. If you want it to do nothing on redelivery, you would have to check for this case in the interceptor route (for example based on Exchange.REDELIVERY_COUNTER)